# Using vectors inside dataframe columns in R

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, element

I am programming a classificator in R, I have cases that can have multiple classes, so I would like to have both classes in the same row and the column somthing$classes, as a vector. What I mean, is that the column something$classes, of the something data.frame should be like a Java or Python lists of lists. Here is an example of the entering data.frame data:

```
Case    class    class1     class2
  A       X                    Z
  B                 Y
  C       X         Y          Z
  D                 Y          Z
```

What I really need to do is to have class, class1 and class2 as one column named classes, with a vector as element, this is the data.frame I would like:

```
Case    classes  
A       [X, Z] %<- This is a vector, not an string      
B       [Y]          
C       [X, Y, Z]
D       [Y, Z]
```

Is there a way of having this data.frame structure? If so, how is done and how I could access an individual element inside each classes vector?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Data.frames support list columns: `DF <- data.frame(a = 1:3); 
DF$b <- list(1:2, 2:3, 3:4)`

Comment: So, I can use something like this in a bucle?: something$classes[i]=list(something$class[i], something$class1[i], something$class2[i]) But this will come in an error if I have some empty elements, like in case A, class1 is empty

Comment: Something in base R would be `df$classes <- apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) list(x[x!=""]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, {v1 <- unlist(.SD); list(classes = list(v1[v1!='']))}, Case]
```

Comment: So, df1 is a new df, or the df I had? I tink I understand that when you do "classes =list(v1[v1!=''])" you are avoyding empty elements, but v1 what exactly is? are you using case as row selector, and the rest of the row should be V1? Thanks!

Comment: @Amnor df1 is the data.frame obect name.  Grouped by 'Case', we are unlisting the other columns, remove the blank elements (`""`) and create a list from the vector elements

Comment: so df1, is the original object, this instruction, if I want my dataframe to be named "eclides" should be as usual: "euclides <- setDT(df1)[, {v1 <- unlist(.SD); list(classes = list(v1[v1!='']))}, Case]" Am I right? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, going for it, just what I needed!!

Comment: Just a little question, for accessing, it should be like "euclides[i]$classes[1]" to acces the element that previously was in class, right?

Comment: It should be `euclides$classes[[1]]`

Comment: Thanks! my [i] is beacuse it is ina bucle using "i" as index. Thanks again for your help!